# Keeping local variables value after rendering page in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, web

I'm trying to create a page using rails. In this page, the user can select items from a list that is available in the page and he needs to be able to see all the items he selected. To do this, i created the following controller and view:

```
class PropostasController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @id_item = params[:id_item]
  end

  def ofertar
    @itens = Item.where(dono_id: session[:id_usuario])
    render "new"
  end

  def adicionar_item
    if !@itens_ofertados
      @itens_ofertados = []
    end
    @itens_ofertados.push(Item.find(params[:id_item]))
    render "new"
  end
end
```

view

```
<h1>Nova Proposta</h1>
<%= @id_item %>
<p>
  Realizar proposta para:
</p>
<div>
  Itens do usuário que receberá a proposta
</div>
<div>
  Itens a serem ofertados:
  <br>
  <%= form_tag("/ofertar_item_proposta") do %>
    <p>
      <%= submit_tag "Ofertar Item" %>
    </p>
  <% end %>

</div>
<div>
<%= render "teste"%>
</div>
<div>
  <br>
  <h2>Itens ofertados</h2>
  <%if @itens_ofertados %>
    <% @itens_ofertados.each do |item| %>
      <ul>
        <li><%= item.nome %></li>
        <li><%= item.descricao %></li>
        <li><%= item.quantidade %></li>
        <li><%= item.categoria.nome %></li>
        <% if item.img_link %>
          <li><%= image_tag(item.img_link, :size => "260x180") %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
</div>
<div>
  <br>
  <h2>Itens a serem selecionados</h2>
  <%if @itens %>
    <% @itens.each do |item| %>
      <%= form_tag("/adicionar_item_proposta") do %>
        <ul>
          <li><%= item.nome %></li>
          <li><%= item.descricao %></li>
          <li><%= item.quantidade %></li>
          <li><%= item.categoria.nome %></li>
          <% if item.img_link %>
            <li><%= image_tag(item.img_link, :size => "260x180") %></li>
          <% end %>
        </ul>
        <ul>
          <%= hidden_field_tag 'id_item', item.id %>
          <li><%= submit_tag 'Adicionar a Proposta' %></li>
        </ul>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

The problem I'm having is that when I click in the submit button of one of the forms of the view, I lose the values that were in @itens_ofertados and in @itens. I want to re render the page or refresh it without losing the previous values of these variables for them to keep appearing in the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@itens_ofertados` is not a local variable. It's an instance variable of your controller.

For each HTTP request, Rails instantiates a new controller instance to handle the request. When the request handling is done, the controller instance dies. So the value of the previous controller's instance variable is inaccessible because that controller instance no longer exists.

The best solution is to store the history in the browser's local storage.

Comment: thank you for the answer, I'm sorry for  my mistake, I don't have much experience with rails. To store in the browser's memory, do I need to store in a session or do I have another resource to do that?

Comment: Session is fine because Rails' default session store is in the cookies. But you should always keep in mind that cookies can only hold 4KB data, and they add up to the network traffic. I suggest storing those data in browser's local storage because it has a much larger volume, and it is never transfered to the server.

Comment: See [local storage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) for detail. It's Javascript.